# What's the difference between heapq and PriorityQueue in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

In python there's a built-in [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) algorithm that gives you `push`, `pop`, `nlargest`, `nsmallest`... etc that you can apply to lists. However, there's also the [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) class that seems to support more or less the same functionality. What's the difference, and when would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`Queue.PriorityQueue` is a thread-safe class, while the `heapq` module makes no thread-safety guarantees. From the [`Queue` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html):

> The `Queue` module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads. The `Queue` class in this module implements all the required locking semantics. It depends on the availability of thread support in Python; see the `threading` module.

The `heapq` module offers no locking, and operates on standard `list` objects, which are not meant to be thread-safe.

In fact, the `PriorityQueue` *implementation* uses `heapq` under the hood to do all prioritisation work, with the base `Queue` class providing the locking to make this thread-safe. See the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Lib/Queue.py#l212) for details.

This makes the `heapq` module faster; there is no locking overhead. In addition, you are free to use the various `heapq` functions in different, novel ways, the `PriorityQueue` only offers the straight-up queueing functionality.

Answer (score 29):

`queue.PriorityQueue` is a partial wrapper around the `heapq` class.

In other words, a `queue.PriorityQueue` is actually a `heapq`, placed in the queue module with a couple of renamed methods to make the `heapq` easier to use, much like a regular queue.

In `heapq`, you use use the method `heappush()` to add a new item and the method `heappop()` to remove one. That is not very queue-like, so `queue.PriorityQueue` let you use the usual queue methods such as `put` and `get` to do the same thing.

There are some features of `heapq` that are not carried over into `queue.PriorityQueue`, such as `heappushpop()` and `heapreplace()`, but you are less likely to use those. If you need them (and I do in my current project), perhaps you should use `heapq` rather than `queue.PriorityQueue`.

Also, since `heapq` is specialized for its purpose, it is not thread safe (as noted in another answer here.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have found the code. It is clear that PriorityQueue uses heapq.

```py
class PriorityQueue(Queue):
    '''Variant of Queue that retrieves open entries in priority order (lowest first).

    Entries are typically tuples of the form:  (priority number, data).
    '''

    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self.queue = []

    def _qsize(self):
        return len(self.queue)

    def _put(self, item):
        heappush(self.queue, item)

    def _get(self):
        return heappop(self.queue)
```